# Django says CSRF token is incorrect or missing when I try to sign in to admin section

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 2.1.1 and I'm following the django release notes can't seem to figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your html template is missing the CSRF token.

It should look something like this:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

Comment: There isn't a html file linked yet. In the django documentation they haven't linked a html file and their admin panel is working without it.